# How to keep strings in yaml from getting converted to times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a yaml file which contains some times:

```
  hours:
    - 00:00:00
    - 00:30:00
    - 01:00:00
```

But as soon as I read them they get converted to time (in seconds), but I want them to remain as strings for a moment so i can do the conversion. Here's how I'm reading them:

```
  def daily_hours
    DefaultsConfig.hours.collect {|hour|
      logger.info { hour.to_s }
    }
  end
```

And it's outputting:

> 0 1800 3600

But I want the strings to remain unchanged to I can convert them to times such as:

> 12:00am 12:30am 1:00am

Why are they getting converted automatically, and how can I stop it?

Here's the DefaultConfig class:

```
class DefaultsConfig  
  def self.load
    config_file = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "defaults.yml")

    if File.exists?(config_file)
      config = ERB.new(File.read(config_file)).result
      config = YAML.load(config)[Rails.env.to_sym]
      config.keys.each do |key|
        cattr_accessor key
        send("#{key}=", config[key])
      end
    end
  end
end
DefaultsConfig.load
```

Comment: How do you set `DefaultConfigs`?

Comment: That's just the class that reads in the yaml file. It gives me access to 'hours' which is what you see in the first gray box in the post.
 I'll add the code to the post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you enclose the value within single quotes, the YAML parser will treat the value as a string.

```
hours:
    - '00:00:00'
    - '00:30:00'
    - '01:00:00'
```

Now when you access the value you will get a string instead of time

```
DefaultsConfig.hours[0] # returns "00:00:00"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! It's weird that it converts it without the single quotes though!

Comment: Essentially you are casting the value to a string by enclosing it in a quote. 
Refer to this article for more details http://eng.genius.com/blog/2009/04/15/yaml-gotchas/

Answer (score 10):

Scalar without quotes or tag is a subject of [implicit type](http://www.yaml.org/type/). You can use quotes or explicit tag:

```
hours:
       - '00:00:01'
       - "00:00:02"
       - !!str "00:00:03"
```